# I can't install heapdump on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, npm, heap-dump, node-heapdump

I am trying to install heapdump so that I can learn to find memory leaks in Node.js apps. I am using Xubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. When I use `npm version` I get

```
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.5.2',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '46',
  node: '4.4.7',
  openssl: '1.0.2h',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  v8: '4.5.103.36',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

I keep running into this error when I try to install heapdump. I am not very familiar with Node.js which makes this harder, but I really need to get this sorted out.

```
ben@bens-omen:~$ npm i heapdump
-
> heapdump@0.3.15 install /home/ben/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:330:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ben/node_modules/heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/home/ben/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "i" "heapdump"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! heapdump@0.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the heapdump@0.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the heapdump package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs heapdump
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls heapdump
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ben/npm-debug.log
```

I am still a fairly novice linux user so I am a little out of my league here. I have spent the last few hours trying to find a solution but nothing seems to work. Am I missing a dependency or something?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not only new to Linux, but also SO. I understand that there are pretty strict rules about posting/removing questions here. I found my answer and I believe that posting the answer here > deleting the question.

After several hours of searching for the answer I found that it was as simple as installing gyp (which I tried to do earlier, just using the wrong commands)

The command to install gyp is `sudo apt install node-gyp`